# ts command in R giving wrong values

Tags: r, time-series

Starting part of my data

```
Month   NBA: (United States)
2004-01                   10
2004-02                   12
2004-03                    9
2004-04                   13
2004-05                   15
2004-06                   17
2004-07                    9
2004-08                    6
2004-09                    5
2004-10                    9
2004-11                   13
2004-12                   10
2005-01                    9
2005-02                   13
2005-03                   11
2005-04                   13
2005-05                   15
2005-06                   19
2005-07                    9
2005-08                    6
2005-09                    5
2005-10                    8
2005-11                   11
2005-12                   11
```

Result of dput(X$searches) -

```
structure(c(56L, 1L, 4L, 54L, 5L, 7L, 9L, 54L, 43L, 38L, 54L, 
5L, 1L, 54L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 7L, 11L, 54L, 43L, 38L, 50L, 3L, 3L, 
1L, 5L, 1L, 5L, 9L, 11L, 54L, 38L, 38L, 50L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 6L, 
1L, 7L, 11L, 10L, 54L, 38L, 38L, 50L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 4L, 8L, 
12L, 12L, 50L, 43L, 38L, 54L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 8L, 4L, 8L, 14L, 12L, 
54L, 38L, 38L, 54L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 7L, 3L, 9L, 13L, 16L, 8L, 46L, 
46L, 5L, 7L, 8L, 10L, 18L, 12L, 22L, 26L, 24L, 50L, 43L, 43L, 
54L, 4L, 14L, 14L, 21L, 17L, 19L, 29L, 36L, 11L, 1L, 50L, 7L, 
13L, 14L, 15L, 20L, 19L, 23L, 30L, 40L, 9L, 54L, 46L, 7L, 14L, 
15L, 14L, 17L, 15L, 26L, 36L, 29L, 13L, 1L, 50L, 8L, 15L, 17L, 
16L, 18L, 15L, 28L, 35L, 42L, 9L, 54L, 1L, 8L, 18L, 21L, 23L, 
27L, 25L, 42L, 48L, 52L, 18L, 4L, 5L, 13L, 24L, 53L, 27L, 32L, 
28L, 45L, 47L, 51L, 19L, 7L, 9L, 24L, 31L, 31L, 33L, 37L, 32L, 
51L, 2L, 44L, 19L, 5L, 7L, 27L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 41L, 34L, 49L, 
55L, 49L, 19L, 5L, 5L, 24L, 35L, 35L, 39L, 39L, 24L, 9L, 8L, 
6L), .Label = c("10", "100", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", 
"17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", 
"28", "29", "30", "32", "33", "34", "36", "37", "38", "40", "41", 
"43", "44", "45", "46", "47", "48", "49", "5", "50", "51", "52", 
"54", "6", "64", "65", "7", "70", "74", "77", "8", "80", "82", 
"86", "9", "99", "NBA: (United States)"), class = "factor")
```

After > `Y = ts(X$searches , frequency = 12, start= c(2004,1))`

Y-

```
    Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec
2004  56   1   4  54   5   7   9  54  43  38  54   5
2005   1  54   5   3   5   7  11  54  43  38  50   3
2006   3   1   5   1   5   9  11  54  38  38  50   1
2007   4   3   6   1   7  11  10  54  38  38  50   3
2008   1   1   6   4   8  12  12  50  43  38  54   4
2009   4   3   8   4   8  14  12  54  38  38  54   3
2010   3   4   7   3   9  13  16   8  46  46   5   7
2011   8  10  18  12  22  26  24  50  43  43  54   4
2012  14  14  21  17  19  29  36  11   1  50   7  13
2013  14  15  20  19  23  30  40   9  54  46   7  14
2014  15  14  17  15  26  36  29  13   1  50   8  15
2015  17  16  18  15  28  35  42   9  54   1   8  18
2016  21  23  27  25  42  48  52  18   4   5  13  24
2017  53  27  32  28  45  47  51  19   7   9  24  31
2018  31  33  37  32  51   2  44  19   5   7  27  35
2019  36  37  41  34  49  55  49  19   5   5  24  35
2020  35  39  39  24   9   8   6
```

What is happening? I want to use this data set for my time series analysis, but the data is getting changed when using ts

Comment: please do not put pictures of your data and code, as nobody can work with it. Just share (part of) your data with `dput` and add properly formatted r code

Comment: `X$searches` is a factor! Eventually you want `Y <- ts(as.numeric(as.character(X$searches)), ...)` https://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#How-do-I-convert-factors-to-numeric_003f

Comment: BTW: "NBA: (United States)" is an element of your vector X$searches

Comment: Oh then I will delete the first row

Comment: Or maybe read the data in with `header = TRUE`?

Comment: I did that and now it is showing "'ts' object must have one or more observations"

Comment: After reading the dataframe, check the structure with `str(X)`.

Comment: Done by deleting only, thank you so much!